# Cargo can't deploy to Tomcat integrated into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

When I try to use the Maven Cargo plugin to deploy to Tomcat embedded in Eclipse, the deployment fails with a 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Eclipse does not include Tomcat's "host-manager" webapp, which is what Cargo uses to deploy remotely. In other words, if your `pom.xml` configures Cargo with `<type>remote</type>`, then Tomcat has to run host-manager.

The standard stand-alone Tomcat installation includes host-manager, but Eclipse doesn't deploy any webapps except the ones you tell it to deploy.

Comment: FYI: the same problem occurs with the tomcat7-maven plugin because it requires a different webapp with a similar name: "Manager" (also deployed by default with Tomcat).